# How to serve Go on a particular path?

Tags: go

How do I make the server listen on `http://localhost:8000/api` as the default URL instead of `http:localhost:8000`?

I've been using this

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8000")
```

What changes should I bring?

Comment: Define all your endpoints with the prefix 'api'. Example: http.Handle("/api/users", usersHandler). Or use mux subRouter and add all your handlers to the subrouter. https://play.golang.org/p/dHoNdi4Ejk8

Comment: Not common, but consider it as an option. Use sub domains instead.  Then the versioning is separated by DNS entries an different ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't listen on a URL, you listen on a TCP port.

So `8080` in your case.

It's up to the server that listens on the port to react on specific URIs.

So to make APIs available on `/api/...`, their path should begin with `/api/`.

```
    http.Handle("/api/someAPI", apiHandler)
    http.Handle("/api/someOtherAPI", otherHandler)
    . . .
```

---

Alternatively when using Kubernetes ingress or some other reverse proxy setup, it's possible to configure URI rewriting ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/1017356/how-to-rewrite-url-to-backend-while-preserving-browser-url-in-nginx-ingress)). This is useful when dealing with an existing application that is hardcoded to a specific URI but needs to be exposed on a different URI.